# Setting "domain" permission on google cloud storage bucket/object - UI or API only?

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to set this permission through the Cloud Console UI for cloud storage? Or is it only settable through the API (for example, [following the guidance in this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gs-discussion/domain%2420permissions/gs-discussion/x0TGU6BMl1w/RqmxVUcRWVYJ))

In the documentation for [Google's cloud storage](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#scopes), one of the defined permission scopes is "domain". This allows you to specify that the read or write permission is granted to any authenticated user that is part of your Google Apps domain.

When accessing a storage container UI in the cloud console, you can set user or group permissions, but entering a naked domain with either "User" or "Group" selected results in an "Invalid Value" message when the changes are saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting is now exposed via the Cloud Console UI. You should notice 3 sections in the dropdown: user, group, and domain.

The setting is also available via the API and via the command-line utility, gsutil. To grant read access to the domain my-domain.org from gsutil, you'd do something like this:

```
gsutil acl ch -g my-domain.org:R gs://bucket
```

Comment: That was what the documentation and CC UI seemed to indicate. Thanks for the confirmation. It would be nice to have the UI at parity with the actual config options, but at least the capability is there.

Comment: FYI: this feature has since been added to the UI. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Just as a point of reference, I'm still seeing this error when trying to add users to a bucket.

Comment: When setting domain access to a file or bucket via UI, I only get `One of your permissions is invalid. Make sure that you enter an authorized id or email for the groups and users and a domain for the domains` Anyone know why?

Comment: "G Suite and Cloud Identity customers can associate their email accounts with an Internet domain name."
The above-mentioned code will only permit requests from email addresses having my-domain.org (eg: xyz@my-domain.org)